# r: ggplot add highlighted annotation to category axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my datafram:

```
test<-read.table(text = "p  VIP log2FC  Name2   Class   Group   Polarity    sign    class.code
0.00302919776   2.624973463 -2.779644484    N1  Steroids and steroid derivatives    TSH pos -1  2
0.00192390970   2.820056443 -2.650407786    N2  Carboxylic acids and derivatives    TCH pos -1  3
0.00063661227   2.695772078 -2.363567645    N3  Carboxylic acids and derivatives    TCH neg -1  3
0.00036276671   2.569894374 -2.283392868    N4  Carboxylic acids and derivatives    TSH neg -1  3
0.00050615743   2.502423281 -2.212932746    N5  Carboxylic acids and derivatives    TSH neg -1  3
0.00007247221   2.592976107 -2.322901045    N6  Azoles  TSH neg -1  11
0.02828910422   2.377676432 -2.345218469    N7  Prenol lipids   TCH pos -1  12
0.00097365202   3.092851245 -3.292899676    N8  Organooxygen compounds  TSH neg -1  13
0.00087925332   2.906452145 -2.864601259    N9  Organooxygen compounds  TCH pos -1  13
0.00070424411   2.961364199 -2.729414896    N10 Organooxygen compounds  TCH neg -1  13
0.00676749126   3.58416488  -2.718140134    N11 Organooxygen compounds  TAH neg -1  13
0.00115934969   2.479875401 -2.442916591    N12 Organooxygen compounds  TSH pos -1  13
0.00000093664   6.911749646 -7.344063359    N13 Benzene and substituted derivatives TAH neg -1  17
0.00072095614   2.98304382  -3.490740824    N14 Flavonoids  TSH pos -1  18
0.04364013849   2.651331909 -3.288365888    N15 Flavonoids  TCH pos -1  18
0.00237961917   2.854364676 -3.239982002    N16 Flavonoids  TSH pos -1  18
0.00079723944   2.923476177 -2.927393648    N17 Flavonoids  TCH pos -1  18
0.04925959046   2.245785308 -2.874095905    N18 Flavonoids  TSH pos -1  18
0.00000103039   2.616765382 -2.618565572    N19 Flavonoids  TSH pos -1  18
0.00345556643   2.553122199 -2.319162288    N20 Flavonoids  TCH pos -1  18
0.00000290000   2.680108814 -2.269663748    N21 Fatty Acyls TCH neg -1  20
0.00035905576   2.366426647 -2.215932235    N22 Fatty Acyls TSH pos -1  20
0.00033629564   2.734465983 -2.89235954 N23 Imidazole ribonucleosides and ribonucleotides   TSH pos -1  23
0.00535643026   3.027317801 -3.725517738    N24 Macrolides and analogues    TSH pos -1  26
0.00846219163   2.56157866  -2.468666494    N25 Macrolides and analogues    TCH pos -1  26
0.00101315825   2.944627274 -2.940716003    N26 Isocoumarans    TCH pos -1  37
0.00136474682   2.546738821 -2.576324693    N27 Isocoumarans    TSH pos -1  37
0.00000310954   3.263175606 -4.022944472    N28 Cycloheptathiophenes    TSH pos -1  39
0.00001238024   3.205283893 -2.939321705    N29 Cycloheptathiophenes    TCH pos -1  39
0.00000001464   2.911252584 -2.850852047    N30 Pyrazolopyridines   TSH neg -1  72",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE,sep = "\t")
```

I plot a scatter plot by this way:

```
library(ggplot2)
test<-test[order(test$class.code),]
ggplot(test,aes(x=Name2,y=log2FC,color=Group,label=Name2))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(aes(size=VIP))+
  scale_color_manual(name="",values = if(v2[i]==c("L")){
    c("#fb9a99","#b2df8a","#a6cee3")
  }else{
    c("#e31a1c","#33a02c","#1f78b4")
  }
  )+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=test$Class)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))
```

like this:

[image]

I am now would like to add some highlighted background to selected positions of the plot since I have ordered the `Class`, what I imagine would like:
[image]

The highlighted background is in line with the position of x axis text, which I have ordered, I have tried `geom_rect` but I don't know how to handel the category axis, and I don't know how to make the width of the hightlighted background to be the same with of the axis text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plot isn't exactly the same as yours (your 'reproducible example' was missing the variable "v2") but here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                        p = c(0.00302919776,
                                              0.0019239097,0.00063661227,
                                              0.00036276671,0.00050615743,7.247221e-05,
                                              0.02828910422,0.00097365202,
                                              0.00087925332,0.00070424411,
                                              0.00676749126,0.00115934969,9.3664e-07,
                                              0.00072095614,0.04364013849,
                                              0.00237961917,0.00079723944,
                                              0.04925959046,1.03039e-06,0.00345556643,
                                              2.9e-06,0.00035905576,
                                              0.00033629564,0.00535643026,
                                              0.00846219163,0.00101315825,0.00136474682,
                                              3.10954e-06,1.238024e-05,
                                              1.464e-08),
                                      VIP = c(2.624973463,
                                              2.820056443,2.695772078,2.569894374,
                                              2.502423281,2.592976107,
                                              2.377676432,3.092851245,2.906452145,
                                              2.961364199,3.58416488,2.479875401,
                                              6.911749646,2.98304382,
                                              2.651331909,2.854364676,2.923476177,
                                              2.245785308,2.616765382,2.553122199,
                                              2.680108814,2.366426647,
                                              2.734465983,3.027317801,2.56157866,
                                              2.944627274,2.546738821,3.263175606,
                                              3.205283893,2.911252584),
                                   log2FC = c(-2.779644484,
                                              -2.650407786,-2.363567645,
                                              -2.283392868,-2.212932746,-2.322901045,
                                              -2.345218469,-3.292899676,
                                              -2.864601259,-2.729414896,-2.718140134,
                                              -2.442916591,-7.344063359,
                                              -3.490740824,-3.288365888,-3.239982002,
                                              -2.927393648,-2.874095905,
                                              -2.618565572,-2.319162288,
                                              -2.269663748,-2.215932235,-2.89235954,
                                              -3.725517738,-2.468666494,
                                              -2.940716003,-2.576324693,-4.022944472,
                                              -2.939321705,-2.850852047),
                                    Name2 = c("N1","N2","N3",
                                              "N4","N5","N6","N7","N8","N9",
                                              "N10","N11","N12","N13","N14",
                                              "N15","N16","N17","N18",
                                              "N19","N20","N21","N22","N23",
                                              "N24","N25","N26","N27","N28",
                                              "N29","N30"),
                                    Class = c("Steroids and steroid derivatives",
                                              "Carboxylic acids and derivatives",
                                              "Carboxylic acids and derivatives",
                                              "Carboxylic acids and derivatives",
                                              "Carboxylic acids and derivatives","Azoles",
                                              "Prenol lipids",
                                              "Organooxygen compounds","Organooxygen compounds",
                                              "Organooxygen compounds",
                                              "Organooxygen compounds",
                                              "Organooxygen compounds",
                                              "Benzene and substituted derivatives","Flavonoids",
                                              "Flavonoids","Flavonoids",
                                              "Flavonoids","Flavonoids","Flavonoids",
                                              "Flavonoids","Fatty Acyls",
                                              "Fatty Acyls",
                                              "Imidazole ribonucleosides and ribonucleotides",
                                              "Macrolides and analogues",
                                              "Macrolides and analogues","Isocoumarans",
                                              "Isocoumarans","Cycloheptathiophenes",
                                              "Cycloheptathiophenes",
                                              "Pyrazolopyridines"),
                                    Group = c("TSH","TCH","TCH",
                                              "TSH","TSH","TSH","TCH",
                                              "TSH","TCH","TCH","TAH","TSH",
                                              "TAH","TSH","TCH","TSH","TCH",
                                              "TSH","TSH","TCH","TCH","TSH",
                                              "TSH","TSH","TCH","TCH","TSH",
                                              "TSH","TCH","TSH"),
                                 Polarity = c("pos","pos","neg",
                                              "neg","neg","neg","pos",
                                              "neg","pos","neg","neg","pos",
                                              "neg","pos","pos","pos","pos",
                                              "pos","pos","pos","neg","pos",
                                              "pos","pos","pos","pos","pos",
                                              "pos","pos","neg"),
                                     sign = c(-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,
                                              -1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,
                                              -1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,
                                              -1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,
                                              -1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L,-1L),
                               class.code = c(2L,3L,3L,3L,3L,
                                              11L,12L,13L,13L,13L,13L,13L,
                                              17L,18L,18L,18L,18L,18L,
                                              18L,18L,20L,20L,23L,26L,26L,
                                              37L,37L,39L,39L,72L)
                       )

test<-test[order(test$class.code),]
ggplot(test,aes(x=Name2,y=log2FC,color=Group,label=Name2))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_rect(xmin = 1, xmax = 5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
            fill = "skyblue", alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 8, xmax = 13, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
            fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 14, xmax = 23, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
            fill = "red", alpha = 0.01) +
  geom_point(aes(size=VIP))+
  # scale_color_manual(name="",values = if(v2[i]==c("L")){
  #   c("#fb9a99","#b2df8a","#a6cee3")
  # }else{
  #   c("#e31a1c","#33a02c","#1f78b4")
  # }
  # )+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=test$Class)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>